# HowTo not hardcode Angular2 environment variables like API Urls

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

With Angular2 you can use `src/environments/environment.ts` and `*.prod.ts` to configure either production or development environments. Now we have a huge staging requirements and we will need e.g. 5-10 API Urls. How to set and read environment variables other than `--prod` or `--dev` with angular-cli, e.g. `URL="http://server12a"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have all different kind of environments.
Define each of those in your angular-cli.json file:

```
  "environments": {
    "local": "environments/environment.ts",
    "test": "environments/environment.test.ts",
    "staging ": "environments/environment.staging.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
```

Within these files you can have something along the lines of:

```
export const environment = {
  URL="http://server12a"
};
```

When you build you have to specify the right environment like:

```
ng build --env=staging
```